# iOS SDK: UITextField Custom Bottom Border

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitextfield, uitextview

I need to make a view with a textfield-textview-textfield-keyboard layout. I'd like to have them all divided by a border like this [tumblr](http://pttrns.com/compose#/detail/0d81d4c6760ce30ec0423ae27a3ea277) view.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Getting 404 on your link, can you please update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to access the `layer` property of `UIView` .

Import the `QuartzCore.h` header file.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Use the below code to set the border and its width.

```
myView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
myView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna give this a shot and see where it gets me.

Comment: @Dan Corrnier NO it will create border on all sides of the textfield. You can try drawing the gray line and use normal textfield. You can create customized view yourself.

Comment: @Dan Cormier : you would consider drawing the gray line between your controls.

Answer (score 1):

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

textView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
textView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [three20](https://github.com/facebook/three20) to accomplish this

Comment: Thank for the suggestion. I've looked into this. I'm already pretty deep into this app, and integrating this framework might be a little messy for such a simple thing. For version 2.0, I'll most likely use this, but I don't think the incentive is there for me at this moment.